# Same word multiple times in a row - longest?

Tags: word-games

Examples:

- Thanks for painting my pub sign, but could you increase the size of the spaces between Bull **and "and" and "and" and** Bush?
- All the faith he **had had had had** no effect on the outcome of his life.

Longest or most interesting one you know of?

Punctuation between the words is allowed, but it must be a single valid sentence.

Comment: The linked duplicate has a sentence with eleven consecutive identical words. But this sort of question is a discussion question, and not on-topic.

Comment: I'm not going to answer this question.

Comment: I'm not *not* going to answer this question.

Comment: I'm not not not not not not not not not not not not not not not not going to not answer this question, am I?

Comment: *I will never never never...* ad infinitum *do as you ask* can go on as long as you like.